# Spark Saving data to MYSQL according to jdbc to other databases

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I try to save rdd to external databases such as mysql according `JDBC To Other Databases`[enter link description here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases).

```
dsStream.foreachRDD( rdd => {
  val to_save_rdd = rdd.map(.../*some tranform operation*/)    
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  to_save_rdd.toDF().show()
  to_save_rdd.toDF().write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306")
  .option("dbtable", "db_name.table_name")
  .option("user", "root")
  .option("password", "root")
  .save()

})
```

However it fails even when i comment *to_save_rdd.toDF().write.format(...).option(...).save*. And the error log is as follows.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: no symbol could be loaded from interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.classification.InterfaceAudience$Public in object InterfaceAudience with name Public and classloader org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader@5d20e46
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$classToScala1(JavaMirrors.scala:1021)
            at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
            at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
            at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:97)
            at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(TwoWayCaches.scala:38)
            at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: That error does not seems matching with the code .

Comment: it Actually matches!  I am working to make a example to reproduce this error!